# curl website with php code problem x-xss-protection

Tags: php, curl, amazon-cloudfront

i have to curl page content web site use cloudfront protection

i use this code for get content but not show all

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://www.tod.tv/en');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'GET');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, [
    'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:109.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/112.0',
    'Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8',
    'Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5',
   // 'Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br',
    'Connection: keep-alive',
    'Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1',
    'Sec-Fetch-Dest: document',
    'Sec-Fetch-Mode: navigate',
    'Sec-Fetch-Site: none',
    'Sec-Fetch-User: ?1',
]);

$response = curl_exec($ch);

curl_close($ch);

echo $response;
```

Comment: That site loads a lot of its contents via JavaScript and fetch (i.e. AJAX). Obviously when you download it via cURL, you're not in a JS environment so cURL/PHP can't execute that JS code. Even if you then echo the downloaded HTML into your browser, any relative links etc in the code will simply point to the wrong place, so it still won't download anything. It's unclear why you expected this to work, or why you appear to be trying to pass someone else's website off as your own. What is the purpose of trying to request this content? Do you have the owner's permission to do so?

Comment: purpose is for education only for how it work and if we can get all content only

Comment: well that's good, you seem to have learned something already, then. You can't. I don't think that has anything to do with CloudFront though.

Comment: If you want to learn about web scraping, pick a site which doesn't use tons of Javascript to load its content